Chromium on latest puppeteer
I want to use Puppeteer to control Chromium in an ARM based ECS container.
My versions are

Puppeteer 23.9.0
Chromium 129.0.6668.100 (This will be getting upgraded).
Node 20 slim

The reason for using Chromium instead of Chrome is that I want to use ARM; my understanding is that Chrome does not currently have a Linux ARM release.
I have run it a few times successfully. Do you know if there are any edge cases or plans I should know about with this setup? Puppeteer is primarily focused on Chrome and Firefox rather than Chromium and is moving from CDP to BiDi.
I'd like to know if something that's working now (Chromium) won't work in the future or if there are other things I should consider that I may not run into during early testing.
